# OTRS Customer Ticket view HowTo pre select Queue

Tags: otrs

with OTRS4 in the New Ticket view in Customer Frontend, there is a To: field with possibility to choose queue. Nice, but, it is allways "-" choosen by default. I want to preselect this to a special queue, so that the customer still has the possibility to choose a queue, but don't have to if they are comfortable with the default.

Best regads,

Hubert

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by trial and error:

In Sysconfig Frontend::Customer::Ticket::ViewNew There is a setting for QueueDefault. Put there the name of your preselected Queue.

Best regards,

Hubert

Comment: This solves the problem only if you don't want to predefine different queues for different customers. There is a setting in the customer user view "default ticket queue", however I cannot select queues there...